# Pythonic way to combine `for` and `try` blocks

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code where I am parsing a JSON feed.

For each array I have code that looks like:

```
for node in parse_me:
    # It's important that one iteration failing doesn't cause all iterations to fail.
    try:
        i = node['id'] # KeyError?
        function_that_needs_int (i) # TypeError?
        # possibly other stuff

    except Exception as e:
        LogErrorMessage ('blah blah blah {} in node {}'.fmt(e, node))
```

I do not like that this makes my for loops double-nested just because I need to stop exceptions from aborting the loop.  Is there a way to flatten this code?

Comment: That looks fine to me, what is the problem?

Comment: That's very fine.. I find it sexier to put `try` outside the loop.

Comment: If the level of nesting bothers you, that means it's time to move stuff into its own function.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, "I need to stop exceptions from aborting the loop".

Comment: Didn't notice that. But I still find it sexier :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun it seems pointless to compare the "sexiness" of two bits of code that don't do at all the same.

Comment: It look fine, but yes, if "# Do a lot of stuff to node" is big you should definitively create a method for this part of code. And then you would decide to put the try catch in the method or not. From my point of view, it's would be nice with a method and the try catch in your for like your example.

Comment: @EvenLisle yeah.. guys.. I said I **didn't** notice that it's different for OP..... In case the logic doesn't matter....

Comment: @jonrsharpe Flat is better than nested.  This for: try: idiom comes up a lot in my code.

Comment: @AlexandreMazel Sometimes it is a lot of code.  Sometimes it is a line or two.  I updated the question with an example of the kind of code you might see.

Comment: @QuestionC yes, but *"Explicit is better than implicit."* and *"Simple is better than complex."*, and your current approach is both simple and explicit! Note, however, that you should use more specific error handling - the `try` block should be as short as possible.

Comment: @QuestionC "Flat is better than nested" *usually* refers to data structures, though you're right that excessive indentation can also be a code smell.

Answer (score 5):

Then you should do things like

```
def iterate_safe(parse_me, message, action):
    for node in parse_me:
        try:
            action(node)
        except Exception as e:
            LogErrorMessage(message.fmt(e, node))
```

and then call it like

```
def action(node):
    do_whatever_must_be_done_with(node)

iterate_safe(parse_me, action, 'blah blah blah {} in node {}')
iterate_safe(parse_me, other_action, 'spam ham {} in node {}')
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The original question seemed to imply that the entire parse operation was in one giant `for`-loop; my answer has been modified to reflect comments below.

Instead of writing multiple `for`-loops, each of which must include a `try`/`catch` block, write functions describing what must be done *within* the loops, and write a decorator to apply to them that will surround each one with the `for`-loop *and* the `try`/`catch` logging logic. This is a bit like glglgl's solution, but a bit more Pythonic (in my opinion). For example:

```
def apply_to_nodes_and_log_errs(node_visit_func):
    def safe_iterating_visitor(nodes_to_parse):
        for node in nodes_to_parse:
            try:
                node_visit_func(node)
            except StandardError as e:
                LogErrorMessage ('blah blah blah {} in node {}'.fmt(e, node))
    return safe_iterating_visitor

@apply_to_nodes_and_log_errs
def action_one(node):
    # ... "lots of stuff" :D

@apply_to_nodes_and_log_errs
def action_two(node):
    # different stuff
```

If you'd rather break the decorator into chunks:

```
def iterate_over_nodelist(node_visit_func):
    def iterating_visitor(nodes_to_parse):
        for node in nodes_to_parse:
            node_visit_func(node)
    return iterating_visitor

def safely_visit_log_errs(node_visit_func):
    def safe_logging_visitor(node_to_visit):
        try:
            node_visit_func(node)
        except StandardError as e:
            LogErrorMessage ('blah blah blah {} in node {}'.fmt(e, node))
    return safe_logging_visitor

def apply_to_nodes_and_log_errs(node_visit_func):
    return iterate_over_nodelist(safely_visit_log_errs(node_visit_func))

# ... write visit functions
```

This could be further improved using [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).

Note that although this may look a little ugly if your standard is "use as few levels of indentation as possible," it's actually quite Pythonic; there's really no way to avoid quite a few indentation levels when writing decorators.

Finally, note that change from `Exception` to `StandardError`, which I still strongly recommend.

Comment: I edited the question with an example of the code that gives us problems.  Sometimes we have to do a lot of work in the `for` body, but sometimes it is just a line or two.  The only consistent thing is this for loop idiom comes up all the time.

My errors mostly stem from the JSON feed's data being bad.  Sometimes data is missing or we get wacky values ("12" in a field that should be an int), and often I just end up in untested cases.

Comment: Every exception I've seen in this application has been a "Data's screwed" exception, so I am not worried about passing exceptions at the moment.  If I start encountering exceptions it makes sense to rethrow, I'll start rethrowing them.

Comment: @QuestionC So you actually have multiple loops, not one big loop? Also, again, the keyboard-interrupt exception is a good example; you have *no idea* when those will occur (regardless of your experience so far with the code), and you should *almost always* rethrow them. At a *minimum*, it is much better to catch `StandardError` rather than `Exception`.

Comment: This is for a parser for a JSON-based grammar.  Each array in the grammar is parsed using a `for: try:` block similar to what I posted above.  So we have as many loops as we have collections in the format.

It reads pretty well (the code basically looks like our business requirements), but the double-nesting of loops because we have to deal with exceptions is annoying.

Comment: @QuestionC I've edited my question to reflect that you're using multiple loops. Note, though, that `try` is not a "loop," so you're not really double-nesting loops regardless of how you implement this.